# the console.log doesn't run in a function that is assigned to a button using onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that is supposed to increment by 1 each time you click the button:

```
<button id="increment-btn" onclick="increment()">INCREMENT</button>
```

the code in js:

```
let count = 0;

function increment() {
  count = count + 1;
  console.log(count);
  return count;
}
```

The code looks perfectly fine to me, but I can't seem to get it to work no matter if I change onclick to onmousedown and the increment after I press the button doesn't show on the console. I used visual studio code to try to make this code work.

Comment: Is the button inside of a set of form tags? If so, the form is probably being submitted. If that is the case just add `type='button'` to the button tag

Comment: it is working https://jsfiddle.net/vuhy3bga/
please check your environment or cache. 
dont forget to enable the disable cache option on chrome dev tool

Comment: How do i check the environment or cache?

Comment: I am using VS as well and when I run the code in the browser there works everything fine. (in the console too)

Comment: Is your Console in Chrome set to "Default levels"? Are some messages filtered out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything should work fine in the Console. One thing that you can change in the code is:

```
let count = 0;

function increment() {
  count++
  console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: Your change to how `count` is incremented is just code style and unnecessary for an answer. That leaves removing the return, which would is considered good practice for event handlers; however, that doesn't require the whole code block; a note would suffice.

Comment: Aside from that, your actual answer consists of "it should work". If that is indeed the case, then the question should be closed as "not reproducible"; it shouldn't be answered.

Comment: (Not intending to be harsh, just direct and to-the-point. Not much time on my hands...)

Comment: its fine i know what the problem is now thank for the help i will close this case

Comment: @Mahad Well, what was the problem? Telling us makes this Q&A useful for everyone, not just you.

Comment: the code works perfectly fine and the problem has more to do with the console in visual studio code. i checked instead the chrome's console and when the button was pressed the numbers did increase while the console in VS code didn't change

Comment: Ok. Yes, the VS code console is not the browser console; the typical one is a command line terminal; you _can_ connect to the browser using certain extensions and entering debug mode.

Comment: Voted to close as "not useful"